# Boost serialization: Linking to libraries

Tags: c++, macos, boost, linker

I want to serialize objects in my program using the Boost library. It is my first time using it and it is giving me some problems.

In my program I have implemented the "serialize" method and include the following:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
```

Now when I build I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::text_oarchive_impl(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      boost::archive::text_oarchive::text_oarchive(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int)in Main.o
  "boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::~basic_oarchive()", referenced from:
      boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::~common_oarchive()in Main.o
      boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::~common_oarchive()in Main.o
      boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::~common_oarchive()in Main.o
  "boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::~basic_text_oprimitive()", referenced from:
      boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::~text_oarchive_impl()in Main.o
      boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::~text_oarchive_impl()in Main.o
      boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::~text_oarchive_impl()in Main.o
  "vtable for boost::archive::archive_exception", referenced from:
      boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)in Main.o
  "typeinfo for boost::archive::archive_exception", referenced from:
      void boost::serialization::throw_exception<boost::archive::archive_exception>(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)in Main.o
  "boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()", referenced from:
      void boost::serialization::throw_exception<boost::archive::archive_exception>(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::save<boost::archive::tracking_type>(boost::archive::tracking_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::save<boost::archive::object_reference_type>(boost::archive::object_reference_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::save<boost::archive::object_id_type>(boost::archive::object_id_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::save<unsigned int>(unsigned int const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::save<boost::archive::class_id_reference_type>(boost::archive::class_id_reference_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::save<boost::archive::class_id_type>(boost::archive::class_id_type const&)in Main.o
      ...
  "boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception::exception_code, char const*, char const*)", referenced from:
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::save<boost::archive::tracking_type>(boost::archive::tracking_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::save<boost::archive::object_reference_type>(boost::archive::object_reference_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::save<boost::archive::object_id_type>(boost::archive::object_id_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::save<unsigned int>(unsigned int const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::save<boost::archive::class_id_reference_type>(boost::archive::class_id_reference_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::save<boost::archive::class_id_type>(boost::archive::class_id_type const&)in Main.o
  "boost::archive::basic_text_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::newtoken()", referenced from:
      void boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save<boost::archive::tracking_type>(boost::archive::tracking_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save<boost::archive::object_reference_type>(boost::archive::object_reference_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save<boost::archive::object_id_type>(boost::archive::object_id_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save<unsigned int>(unsigned int const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save<boost::archive::class_id_reference_type>(boost::archive::class_id_reference_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save<boost::archive::class_id_type>(boost::archive::class_id_type const&)in Main.o
  "boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::end_preamble()", referenced from:
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, boost::archive::tracking_type>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, boost::archive::tracking_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, boost::archive::object_reference_type>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, boost::archive::object_reference_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, boost::archive::object_id_type>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, boost::archive::object_id_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, boost::archive::version_type>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, boost::archive::version_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, boost::archive::class_id_reference_type>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, boost::archive::class_id_reference_type const&)in Main.o
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, boost::archive::class_id_type>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, boost::archive::class_id_type const&)in Main.o
      ...
  "boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in Main.o
  "typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive", referenced from:
      typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>in Main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [stable] Error 1
```

I am not sure if the problem is because of linking or if it has something to do with 64 bit and 32 bit architecture.

I have tried linking with:

```
-L/opt/local/lib/ -lboost_iostreams -lboost_serialization
```

But it does not seem to do any difference.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your boost library bundle is 32 bit only; you'll have to rebuild it adding 64 bit binaries, or set your main project to match the boost libraries.
Try setting your project to generate a 32 bit binary instead of 64 bit. In XCode 4.2, you'd use the Architecture section of the build settings in the project inspector.

Answer (score 1):

In my case: It is because I used compiler gcc6 (or gcc5 has same issue). And my code used different compile flag with boost libraries. Detail explanation is in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring)

If you can recompile all incompatible libs you use, do it with compiler option

```
-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1
```

and then rebuild your project. If still can not link, add change project's makefile compiler option to 0.

```
-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
```