# GeoDjango GDAL installation

Tags: c++, installation, gdal, geodjango

I have been working through the installation of GeoDjango and I have run into problems when installing the `GDAL library`.  I'm running `ubuntu 16.04` and I have installed `GEOS` and `PROJ.4`, I'm working with a `PostGIS` installation.  I previously had a version of python 3.5
 installed and went through uninstalling it to see if that resolved the issue.  On make i receive the following error:

```
/home/matt/geodjango/gdal-1.11.2/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream()'
/home/matt/geodjango/gdal-1.11.2/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find(char, unsigned long) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
GNUmakefile:46: recipe for target 'gdalinfo' failed
make[1]: *** [gdalinfo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/matt/geodjango/gdal-1.11.2/apps'
GNUmakefile:69: recipe for target 'apps-target' failed
make: *** [apps-target] Error 2
```

I found [Converting std::__cxx11::string to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring)  but I'm not sure how to implement this solution.  Are there other suggestions to successfully install GDAL?

Answer (score 1):

I tried:

```
pip install gdal
```

which failed with:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yOu25c/gdal/
```

and:

```
easy_install gdal
```

failed with:

```
setuptools.sandbox.UnpickleableException: gdal_config_error(OSError(2, 'No such file or directory'),)
```

I was able to run :

```
conda install gdal
```

which worked and returns true for:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis import gdal
>>> gdal.HAS_GDAL
true
```

Answer (score 0):

*postgis* and *GDAL* can be installed directly from ubuntu's [repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/postgis):

```
sudo apt-get install postgis
```