# The procedure entry point _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: c++, string, variables, stdstring

Lately I have been trying to store strings in variables. I did quite a few searches online, and most of the answers that I have found recommend the use of std::string. So I've written a test program that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);
    cout << s;
}
```

The program compiles fine, however, when I run the program I revieve this error:`[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsNXz.png)

I am a huge beginner to programming and confused on what is going on. Can anyone please give me some insight on what is happening here? Thanks!

Also, I am using the GCC compiler.

EDIT: I have successfully solved the issue. All I did was reinstall GCC using a tutorial on the web. I do not know what was wrong, but it is fixed now.

Comment: How are you compiling your code?

Comment: Use g++ instead of gcc.  The second links the standard library automatically.

Comment: The missing symbol (after I fixed the typos) demangles to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()` which is better known as the default constructor for `std::string`. This is likely to be an installation problem.

Comment: You should show your command to compile the program. If you have not done so, then use `g++` instead of `gcc`; or use `gcc -x c++` to force c++ compilation. Also see [Converting std::__cxx11::string to std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33394934/608639) on Stack Overflow and [GCC5 and the C++11 ABI](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/) on the Red Hat blog.

Comment: My compile code is "g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test.exe" what do you think I should change to make this compile? Forgive me if you already answered this, but I am still very beginner so I'm not familiar with all this yet.

Comment: @Zachary try compiling your code using `clang++ `.

Answer (score 2):

When you use GCC to compile C++, you need to use the `g++` driver program, not `gcc`. The latter will compile the translation units, but it will not link the executable correctly.

Comment: The compile code is "g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test.exe" however, I am still getting the same error

Comment: @Zachary: Ah, see jww's comment above the regarding GCC's recent ABI change.