# Storing std::string as character array

Tags: c++, string, c++11, c-strings

I'm trying to convert an `std::string` into a c string (my real problem is closer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring); I'm trying a workaround).

1. How does one store an `std::string` as a character array?
2. Why do std::string.data() and std::string.c_str() return `char [(<anonymous> + 1)]` instead of the expected  `const char*`? Or do I have these mixed up, and if so, how do I work with these types?

   ```
   #include <string>
   #include <iostream>

   int main()
   {
     std::string sstring = "I'm an std string!";

     char cstring[sstring.size()];

     cstring = sstring.c_str();
     std::cout << std::string(sstring.c_str());

     return 0;
   }
   ```

Compilation results in

```
scratch.cpp:10:11: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char*’ to ‘char [(<anonymous> + 1)]’
```

I wasn't able to find a relevant, preexisting question.

Comment: `std::string::data()` and `std::sring::c_str()` return `const char*`.

Comment: Why do you think `.c_str()` returns `char [(<anonymous> + 1)]`?

Comment: Why are you assigning a pointer to an array?

Comment: This is a blatant [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) scenario. Please state your real problem.

Comment: The correct way to copy cstrings between char arrays is [`std::strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy). The statement `cstring = sstring.c_str();` is trying to assign directly to an array but c arrays are not assignable. Note that `char cstring[sstring.size()];` is not standard c++, but some compiler support it as an extension. It's not portable.

Comment: They do return `const char*`; `char [(<anonymous> + 1)]` is the type of your (non-standard) array. (`x = y` assigns `y` to `x`, not `x` to `y`.)

Comment: Just use `const auto cstring = sstring.c_str();` . Btw; the deduced type of `cstring` will be `const char*`.

Comment: @kennytm this is indeed an XY problem scenario. However, I very much feel I should know how to solve problem Y, and would like to learn to do so regardless.

Comment: The thing is, we don't know what problem Y actually is because we don't know the circumstance in which you encountered it because you didn't actually encounter it. It's not clear what the code is trying to do. Why isn't just calling `c_str()` and using the result sufficient?

Comment: @melpomene I may be wrong. I though that ```c_str() returns ```char [(<anonymous> +1)]``` because this is what g++ complained about.

Comment: @jogama It returns `const char *`, more or less.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz pardon; this is my first question on SO. The code I posted is self-contained; it's just that snippet compiled with ```g++ -std=c++11 scratch.cpp```. I'm not sure how I can further clarify Y; it's entirely the code in the question.

Comment: There's no question in the question. If the question is "why do I get that error message", the answer is that you can't use an array as an lvalue in C or C++. If you want to fill an array with values, you have to copy them in. So it's attempting to do something nonsensical. How you fix it depends on why you attempted to do something nonsensical, which we don't know.

Comment: @jogama No, g++ is complaining that you're trying to assign to `char [(<anonymous> + 1)]`, which is the type of the `cstring` array in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this sound like an XY problem. But if you simply want to copy the string you can do it like so:

```
char cstring[sstring.size() + 1];
strcpy(cstring, sstring.c_str());
```

Just be aware that VLAs are not a part of C++ but g++ will 'go with it', see answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard).

Comment: Thank you! I should have known this; I don't know how I forgot to copy c strings.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a  `const char *`

```
  std::string sstring = "I'm an std string!";

  const char * cstring = sstring.c_str();

  std::cout << cstring << std::endl;
```

Comment: Or just use `auto` and let the compiler deduce the correct type ;-)

Answer (score -3):

A working way to assign your string to a char array is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::string s = "HELLO WORLD!";
  char *cs = (char *)s.c_str();

  std::cout << cs << '\n' << std::string(cs) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image: CODE OUTPUT]

This works because it casts the `const char *` to `char *` and therefore allows the assignment to go through, and although this may not be the best way it is very simple.