# Linker errors even though CMake correctly locates the relevant .so file

Tags: linux, boost, makefile, cmake, linker

*Note: I am using a shared system running RedHat Linux, so I cannot use apt-get nor sudo*

I am attempting to compile a program ([OpenMVS](https://github.com/cdcseacave/openMVS)) via a makefile generated by CMake. First I run:

`cmake . ../openMVS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/u/llipson/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DVCG_ROOT="$HOME/vcglib"`

Then, I run `make` to execute the makefiles generated by CMake. However, `make` fails during the linking step due to the following "undefined reference to" errors:

```
[[llipson@head openMVS_build]$ make
[ 18%] Built target Common
[ 26%] Built target Math
[ 49%] Built target IO
[ 77%] Built target MVS
[ 79%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/InterfaceCOLMAP
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<bool, char>::xparse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&) const':
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIbcE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaISB_EE[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIbcE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaISB_EE]+0x17): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool*, int)'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char>::xparse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&) const':
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorIS7_SaIS7_EE[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcE6xparseERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorIS7_SaIS7_EE]+0x17): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, int)'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<int, char>::name() const':
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIicE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIicE4nameEv]+0x1d): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg[abi:cxx11]'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<unsigned int, char>::name() const':
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIjcE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIjcE4nameEv]+0x1d): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg[abi:cxx11]'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<bool, char>::name() const':
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIbcE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIbcE4nameEv]+0x1d): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg[abi:cxx11]'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char>::name() const':
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcE4nameEv]+0x1d): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg[abi:cxx11]'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::basic_command_line_parser(int, char const* const*)':
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC2EiPKPKc[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC5EiPKPKc]+0x200): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::to_internal(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC2EiPKPKc[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC5EiPKPKc]+0x298): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o: In function `Initialize(unsigned long, char const**)':
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._Z10InitializemPPKc+0x1e4): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._Z10InitializemPPKc+0x758): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._Z10InitializemPPKc+0x151b): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o: In function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const& boost::program_options::validators::get_single_string<char>(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool)':
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options10validators17get_single_stringIcEERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EEERKSt6vectorIS9_SaIS9_EEb[_ZN5boost15program_options10validators17get_single_stringIcEERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EEERKSt6vectorIS9_SaIS9_EEb]+0x6f): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validation_error::get_template[abi:cxx11](boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t)'
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options10validators17get_single_stringIcEERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EEERKSt6vectorIS9_SaIS9_EEb[_ZN5boost15program_options10validators17get_single_stringIcEERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EEERKSt6vectorIS9_SaIS9_EEb]+0x83): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::error_with_option_name(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options10validators17get_single_stringIcEERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EEERKSt6vectorIS9_SaIS9_EEb[_ZN5boost15program_options10validators17get_single_stringIcEERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EEERKSt6vectorIS9_SaIS9_EEb]+0x144): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validation_error::get_template[abi:cxx11](boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t)'
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options10validators17get_single_stringIcEERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EEERKSt6vectorIS9_SaIS9_EEb[_ZN5boost15program_options10validators17get_single_stringIcEERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EEERKSt6vectorIS9_SaIS9_EEb]+0x158): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::error_with_option_name(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o: In function `void boost::program_options::validate<int, char>(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, int*, long)':
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options8validateIicEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT0_St11char_traitsIS7_ESaIS7_EEESaISB_EEPT_l[_ZN5boost15program_options8validateIicEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT0_St11char_traitsIS7_ESaIS7_EEESaISB_EEPT_l]+0x1af): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::invalid_option_value::invalid_option_value(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o: In function `void boost::program_options::validate<unsigned int, char>(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, unsigned int*, long)':
InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options8validateIjcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT0_St11char_traitsIS7_ESaIS7_EEESaISB_EEPT_l[_ZN5boost15program_options8validateIjcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT0_St11char_traitsIS7_ESaIS7_EEESaISB_EEPT_l]+0x176): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::invalid_option_value::invalid_option_value(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEcEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool) const'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIjcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIjcEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool) const'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIicEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIicEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool) const'
CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIbcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIbcEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/InterfaceCOLMAP] Error 1
make[1]: *** [apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Evidently, the makefile for the particular executable can't find the object file containing the boost::program_options methods, which is `/u/llipson/lib/libboost_program_options.so`. However, I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so CMake correctly identifies the location of the boost library as `/u/llipson/lib/` (as confirmed by printing the Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS variable in CMakeLists.txt), and the generated makefile even has the correct path to the .so file as a prerequisite for building the target:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.15

# Delete rule output on recipe failure.
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:


#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /n/fs/pvl/llipson/cmake-3.15.0-rc1-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /n/fs/pvl/llipson/cmake-3.15.0-rc1-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /u/llipson/openMVS

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /u/llipson/openMVS_build

# Include any dependencies generated for this target.
include apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/depend.make

# Include the progress variables for this target.
include apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/progress.make

# Include the compile flags for this target's objects.
include apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/flags.make

apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o: apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/flags.make
apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o: /u/llipson/openMVS/apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --progress-dir=/u/llipson/openMVS_build/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_1) "Building CXX object apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o"
    cd /u/llipson/openMVS_build/apps/InterfaceCOLMAP && /u/llipson/gcc-5.3.0/bin/g++  $(CXX_DEFINES) $(CXX_INCLUDES) $(CXX_FLAGS) -o CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o -c /u/llipson/openMVS/apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp

apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.i: cmake_force
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green "Preprocessing CXX source to CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.i"
    cd /u/llipson/openMVS_build/apps/InterfaceCOLMAP && /u/llipson/gcc-5.3.0/bin/g++ $(CXX_DEFINES) $(CXX_INCLUDES) $(CXX_FLAGS) -E /u/llipson/openMVS/apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp > CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.i

apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.s: cmake_force
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green "Compiling CXX source to assembly CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.s"
    cd /u/llipson/openMVS_build/apps/InterfaceCOLMAP && /u/llipson/gcc-5.3.0/bin/g++ $(CXX_DEFINES) $(CXX_INCLUDES) $(CXX_FLAGS) -S /u/llipson/openMVS/apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp -o CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.s

# Object files for target InterfaceCOLMAP
InterfaceCOLMAP_OBJECTS = \
"CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o"

# External object files for target InterfaceCOLMAP
InterfaceCOLMAP_EXTERNAL_OBJECTS =

bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/InterfaceCOLMAP.cpp.o
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/build.make
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: lib/libMVS.a
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: lib/libMath.a
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: lib/libIO.a
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: lib/libCommon.a
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libboost_iostreams.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libboost_program_options.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libboost_serialization.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libboost_regex.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_dnn.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_gapi.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_ml.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_objdetect.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_photo.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_stitching.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_video.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_calib3d.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_features2d.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_flann.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib64/libopencv_core.so.4.0.1
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libpng.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /usr/lib64/libz.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libtiff.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /n/fs/pvl/llipson/CGAL-4.13.1/lib/libCGAL.so.13.0.2
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libgmp.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libboost_thread.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libboost_chrono.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libboost_date_time.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libboost_atomic.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /n/fs/pvl/llipson/CGAL-4.13.1/lib/libCGAL_Core.so.13.0.2
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /n/fs/pvl/llipson/CGAL-4.13.1/lib/libCGAL_ImageIO.so.13.0.2
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libgmp.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libboost_thread.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libboost_chrono.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libboost_date_time.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libboost_atomic.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /n/fs/pvl/llipson/CGAL-4.13.1/lib/libCGAL_Core.so.13.0.2
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /n/fs/pvl/llipson/CGAL-4.13.1/lib/libCGAL_ImageIO.so.13.0.2
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /u/llipson/lib/libboost_system.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: /usr/lib64/libcuda.so
bin/InterfaceCOLMAP: apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/link.txt
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --bold --progress-dir=/u/llipson/openMVS_build/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_2) "Linking CXX executable ../../bin/InterfaceCOLMAP"
    cd /u/llipson/openMVS_build/apps/InterfaceCOLMAP && $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/link.txt --verbose=$(VERBOSE)

# Rule to build all files generated by this target.
apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/build: bin/InterfaceCOLMAP

.PHONY : apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/build

apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/clean:
    cd /u/llipson/openMVS_build/apps/InterfaceCOLMAP && $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -P CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/cmake_clean.cmake
.PHONY : apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/clean

apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/depend:
    cd /u/llipson/openMVS_build && $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /u/llipson/openMVS /u/llipson/openMVS/apps/InterfaceCOLMAP /u/llipson/openMVS_build /u/llipson/openMVS_build/apps/InterfaceCOLMAP /u/llipson/openMVS_build/apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=$(COLOR)
.PHONY : apps/InterfaceCOLMAP/CMakeFiles/InterfaceCOLMAP.dir/depend
```

I am using GNU compiler version 5.3.0

Is there any other way to resolve these linker errors, or perhaps other things I should try?

Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Included the full error message. Also included the makefile generated by CMake

Comment: **Exact error message**, please. It should show linking which file cause the errors and complete (not truncated) functions names which are missed.

Comment: The linker links with `.a` files, not `.so` files. Where is the `.a` file?

Comment: `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a macOS thing.  The Linux equivalent is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  With that said, I don't think either one of those is relevant to the *static* linking performed at compile time, which is where your failures are occurring (notwithstanding that the library involved is a shared object).

Comment: @kenba It's actually in the same location, i.e. in /u/llipson/lib/

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah ok. So it should be looking for /u/llipson/lib/libboost_program_options.a?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean at all.  The (static) linker will link your shared objects to the executable at compile time if that's what it finds.  I'm saying that it will not use the `[SY]LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to find them -- that's relevant to a different program and different circumstances.

Comment: I see all missed functions has `__cxx11` component. Probably, the Boost libraries you have are **incompatible** with the compiler you use: the compiler uses pre-c++11 standard, but the Boost libraries compiled with fully c++11 compiler. See also that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ah, I didn't realize the significance of that part of the error message, I just assumed that it couldn't find the boost library. The issue was exactly as you said, and recompiling boost with the correct CXX11 ABI fixed the issue. Thanks!