# Simulink Rapid accelerator mode compiler error Linux CentOS 7.3 undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, simulink, matlab-compiler, rtw

Currently I am trying to run my Simulink model, built with Matlab 2019b, on a server of my university, which runs on Linux CentOS 7.3.1611. If I run the model in either 'normal', or 'accelerator' mode it is successful. However, if I try to run the model in 'rapid accelerator mode' the compiler returns an error during building. The errors all contain the element of not finding the standard library:

```
undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>
```

I have searched on MATLAB Answers and stackoverflow for solutions, but none have worked for me so far. I have also asked the IT service of my university for help but they could not help me out.

[One of the solutions](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/476164-simulink-issue-when-trying-to-compile-using-rapid-accelerator-mode) hinted towards the compiler not being able to find the correct libraries and that the library path should be added/updated here on stack overflow. However, if I print the Library path in matlab then it seems allright:
Library path:

```
<matlab_root>/cefclient/sys/os/glnxa64:<matlab_root>/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64:<matlab_root>/sys/os/glnxa64:<matlab_root>/bin/glnxa64:<matlab_root>/extern/lib/glnxa64:<matlab_root>/runtime/glnxa64:<matlab_root>/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:
<matlab_root>/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:<compiler_root>/root/usr/lib64:<compiler_root>/root/usr/lib:<compiler_root>/root/usr/lib64/dyninst
```

Another problem could be the compiler. At first I used a gcc 8.x compiler, but later found out that a 6.3 version is required, so that is what I am using now

Lastly I found a that a problem could be that "(...) it probably indicates that you are trying to link together object  files that were compiled with different values for the  _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI macro."  ([from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring))
The last option seems the most likely to me, however, I have not been able to solve this. I tried for instance:

```
set_param(model,'AccelMakeCommand','make_rtw CPP_OPTS="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"')
```

and

```
set_param(model,'MakeCommand','make_rtw CPP_OPTS="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"')
```

However, this did not help.

If anyone has a tip that could help me out, that would be great. I have added parts of the console output and the error message were it goes wrong down below for extra info.

Kind regards,
Nathan

**Console output messages:**

```
 ( A lot of other stuff)
    ### Processing Template Makefile: <matlab_root>/rtw/c/raccel/raccel_unix.tmf
    ### <model_folder>/slprj/raccel/MyModel/MyModel.mk which is generated from <matlab_root>/rtw/c/raccel/raccel_unix.tmf is up to date
    ### Building MyModel: <matlab_root>/bin/glnxa64/gmake -f MyModel.mk  RSIM_SOLVER_SELECTION=2 PCMATLABROOT="<matlab_root>" EXTMODE_STATIC_ALLOC=0 EXTMODE_STATIC_ALLOC_SIZE=1000000 EXTMODE_TRANSPORT=0 TMW_EXTMODE_TESTING=0 COMBINE_OUTPUT_UPDATE_FCNS=0 INCLUDE_MDL_TERMINATE_FCN=1 MULTI_INSTANCE_CODE=0 MODELREF_TARGET_TYPE=NONE ISPROTECTINGMODEL=NOTPROTECTING OPTS="-DTGT
     an error.
```

**Error message:**

```
 ( A lot of stuff)
    g++  -Wl,-rpath,<matlab_root>/sys/os/glnxa64
    -L<matlab_root>/sys/os/glnxa64 -o MyModel
    MyModel_c233cdf9_1.o MyModel_c233cdf9_1_create.o
    MyModel_c233cdf9_1_setParameters.o
    MyModel_c233cdf9_1_asserts.o
    MyModel_c233cdf9_1_deriv.o
    MyModel_c233cdf9_1_checkDynamics.o
    MyModel_c233cdf9_1_output.o
    MyModel_c233cdf9_1_assembly.o
    MyModel_c233cdf9_1_computeConstraintError.o
    MyModel_c233cdf9_1_mode_zero_crossings.o
    MyModel_c233cdf9_1_geometries.o
    MyModel_c233cdf9_1_gateway.o pm_printf.o rt_logging.o
    rt_backsubrr_dbl.o rt_forwardsubrr_dbl.o rt_lu_real.o rt_matrixlib_dbl.o
    MyModel.o MyModel_capi.o
    MyModel_data.o MyModel_tgtconn.o rtGetInf.o
    rtGetNaN.o rt_nonfinite.o rt_logging_mmi.o rtw_modelmap_utils.o
    raccel_main_new.o raccel_sup.o raccel_mat.o simulink_solver_api.o
    raccel_utils.o common_utils.o ext_svr.o updown.o ext_work.o
    rtiostream_interface.o rtiostream_tcpip.o rtiostream_utils.o   \
             <matlab_root>/toolbox/physmod/sm/ssci/lib/glnxa64/sm_ssci_std.a
                 <matlab_root>/toolbox/physmod/sm/core/lib/glnxa64/sm_std.a
                 <matlab_root>/toolbox/physmod/pm_math/lib/glnxa64/pm_math_std.a
                 <matlab_root>/toolbox/physmod/simscape/engine/sli/lib/glnxa64/ssc_sli_std.a
                 <matlab_root>/toolbox/physmod/simscape/engine/core/lib/glnxa64/ssc_core_std.a
                 <matlab_root>/toolbox/physmod/network_engine/lib/glnxa64/ne_std.a
                 <matlab_root>/toolbox/physmod/common/math/core/lib/glnxa64/mc_std.a
                 <matlab_root>/toolbox/physmod/common/external/library/lib/glnxa64/ex_std.a
                 <matlab_root>/toolbox/physmod/common/foundation/core/lib/glnxa64/pm_std.a
                 <matlab_root>/bin/glnxa64/libmwcoder_target_services.so
                 <matlab_root>/bin/glnxa64/libmwcoder_ParamTuningTgtAppSvc.so
                 -L"<matlab_root>/bin/glnxa64" -lmwipp -lut -lmx -lmex
                 -lmat -lmwmathutil -lmwslexec_simbridge -lmwsl_fileio
                 -lmwsigstream -lmwsl_AsyncioQueue -lmwsl_services
                 -lmwsdi_raccel -lmwi18n -lmwsl_simtarget_instrumentation
                 -lfixedpoint -lmwslexec_simlog -lm -lpthread -ldl
    <matlab_root>/bin/glnxa64/libQt5WebKit.so.5: undefined reference to
    `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
    std::allocator<char> >::_S_copy(char*, char const*, unsigned
    long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
    <matlab_root>/bin/glnxa64/libmwboost_locale.so.1.65.1: undefined
    reference to `std::__cxx11::numpunct<char>::id@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
    <matlab_root>/bin/glnxa64/libmwboost_serialization.so.1.65.1:
    undefined reference to `typeinfo for
    std::__codecvt_utf8_base<wchar_t>@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
    <matlab_root>/bin/glnxa64/libut.so: undefined reference to
    `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
    std::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
    <matlab_root>/bin/glnxa64/libut.so: undefined reference to
    `std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
    <matlab_root>/bin/glnxa64/libmwcoder_target_services.so: undefined
    reference to `typeinfo for std::_V2::error_category@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
    <matlab_root>/bin/glnxa64/libmwboost_locale.so.1.65.1: undefined
    reference to `typeinfo for std::__cxx11::moneypunct_byname<char,
    false>@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
   
     ( A lot of stuff)

         collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    gmake: *** [MyModel] Error 1

    Error(s) encountered while building "MyModel" - Show complete
    stack trace
}
```