# undifine reference [abi:cxx11]

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I have a project that I'm compiling with GCC 7.3  c++ 17,
my project link to 3rd party lib that builds with GCC 7.3 but with c++11.
when I'm trying to link the lib I'm getting `undefined reference to ec_core::ECPassword::getPlainText[abi:cxx11]()`
I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring) question but with no luck.
I'm using CMake.
If I'm adding to the CMake file

```
add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1)
```

and in the code I'm doing this:

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0
    ec_framework::ConfigRP _ecconfig = m_ecapp->load(path, fileName, "ver_num");
#undef _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
```

Im gtting the same error
and if I'm doing the opesit AS

```
add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
```

I'm getting a lot of undefined references on other functions.
and also if I'm surrounding them with

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 1
    function_name;
#undef _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
```

it's not helping.
is there a way to link them together?

Comment: That macro only does something useful at the time you include standard library headers, like you do with `add_definitions`

Comment: @Botje so is there a different way to fix this problome?

Comment: Step one is to check whether the third-party actually contains the missing symbol and step two is to verify whether you're actually correctly linking to it. If you know how the library was built exactly, that is also good to know.

Comment: @Botje this is the output of `nm` command `nm libec-core.so |grep "ECApplication.*load"
000000000006bce0 T _ZN7ec_core13ECApplication4loadERKSsS2_PKc`

Comment: That means the third-party library is not compiled with the cxx11 ABI. Presumably your application is? You should recompile the library *with* cxx11 support or your application *without* cxx11, and preferably with the same compiler version.

Comment: @Botje how do you can tell that the lib compiled with or without the cxx11 ABI?

Comment: Because "Ss" in the mangled symbol name is an abbreviation for `std::string` in the old ABI. With `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1` I get `_ZN7ec_core13ECApplicationL4loadERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PKc` instead.

Comment: @Botje so i need to build my project with `add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)`?

Comment: or recompile the library with the CXX11 ABI, yes. You cannot mix both in one application and I expect you link with other libraries that *do* use the CXX11 ABI.

Comment: @Botje I change the macro and now Im getitng aa lot of `undefined reference` on other fucntion  `undefined reference` to `md_framework::Config::getAttrValue(char const*) const'` i run the `nm` command again and this is the output `000000000005c6e0 T _ZNK12ec_framework6Config12getAttrValueEPKc
000000000005c7a0 T _ZNK12ec_framework6Config12getAttrValueEPKcS2_
000000000005af30 T _ZNK12ec_framework6Config12getAttrValueERKSs
000000000005ae10 T _ZNK12ec_framework6Config12getAttrValueERKSsS2_
`

Comment: md_framework != ec_framework. Please ensure you are linking to a library that contains the correct symbol .

Comment: @Botje last night I got the new lib with c++ 11 ABI and it works, thank you very much. writ it as an answer and I will accept it.