# VSCode ESP32 type error in Serial.println

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino, esp32

I decided to switch from the Arduino IDE to VSCode and PlatformIO for my ESP32. I am using the BLE Server example with a callback, as a test:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>

#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

class MyCallBack: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {

    void onRead(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      std::__cxx11::string val = pCharacteristic->getValue();
      if ((val.length() > 0)) {
        Serial.println(val);
      }
    }
    
};
    

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting BLE work!");

  BLEDevice::init("Long name works now");
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                         CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ
                                       );

  pCharacteristic->setValue("Hello World!");
  pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallBack());
  pService->start();
  // BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();  // this still is working for backward compatibility
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(true);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x06);  // functions that help with iPhone connections issue
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x12);
  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
  Serial.println("Characteristic defined! Now you can read it in your phone!");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(2000);
}
```

I'm pretty sure when I was using this in the Arduino IDE it uploaded and ran fine but in VSCode I am getting an error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "HardwareSerial::println" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::__cxx11::string) -- object type is: HardwareSerial
```

Except `getValue` of `BLECharacteristic` returns `std::__cxx11::string`.

I have also tried `#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0` according to: [Converting std::__cxx11::string to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring) but I get the same error just with `std::string` instead.

If `getValue` returns the right type, why I am not able to print the value to the Serial?

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing is complaining that the compiler can't locate a version of the `println` method of `HardwareSerial` that takes `std::__cxx11::string` as an argument. The problem isn't that the `getValue()` method returns the wrong thing; the problem is that `Serial.println()` isn't written to accept what `getValue()` returns as an argument.

You need to cast or otherwise convert the `std::__cxx11::string` that the Bluetooth functions are returning to a `String` or `char *`, both of which the `println()` method accepts. You can use the `.c_str()` method to do this.

```
      if ((val.length() > 0)) {
        Serial.println(val.c_str());
      }
```

You could find this by reading documentation on `Serial.println` and `std::__cxx11::string`.

Comment: Ah ok. I was interpreting the error wrong I guess. When it said about arguments types I though that was the type it wanted but actually that is the type I gave it. Using the `c_str` method works - thanks!