# undefined reference to `(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' when using tensorflow_cc.so

Tags: c++11, gcc, tensorflow2.0

I am working on linking Tensorflow2 shared libraries (*.so) files into my C++ program. The libtensorflow_cc and libtensorflow_framework.so use bazel-3.7.2 and gcc7.3 and is linked to another library I have ‘libmyproj.so’. I want to link this libmyproj.so to my main program which are built with the same gcc7.3. I have tried using the -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 flag for ABI compatibility (from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source and [Converting std::__cxx11::string to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring)) but without any success. I am stuck at the following error:

> `undefined reference to ml_model::ml_model(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'` `undefined reference to ml_model::preprocess_data(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, int&, int&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)'` `undefined reference to ml_model::get_predictions(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)'`
> in function std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits,
> std::allocator >* tensorflow::internal::MakeCheckOpString<long,
> int>(long const&, int const&, char const*)': `undefined reference to tensorflow::internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString[abi:cxx11]()'`

Any suggestions on why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

Check if the `libstdc++` version is correct。 Your problem may be the `tensorflow_cc.so` compiler with higher `libstdc++` version, but your build env `libstdc++`  is lower, so some symbols will not be found.

- Get libstdc++ version:

  ```
  bash$ /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep stdc++
           libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x86_64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
  bash$ ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jan 10  2021 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.28
  ```

  The symlink points to a versioned file, in this case 6.0.28.
- Update `libstdc++`; how to do this exactly depends on your distro, but instructions should not be hard to find in Google.