# Openfoam whiling compilation

Tags: c, compilation, openfoam

While compiling Openfoam on a cluster I have getting an error.

```
source
/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/etc/bashrc;

wmake -j 44
Compiling enabled on 44 cores
Making dependency list for source file simpleFoam.C
g++ -std=c++11 -m64 -Dlinux64 -DWM_ARCH_OPTION=64 -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32
-Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-cast -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-unused-parameter
-Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-attributes -O3
-Wl,-rpath,/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32-spack/lib
-DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -I./include
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/MomentumTransportModels/momentumTransportModels/lnInclude
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/MomentumTransportModels/incompressible/lnInclude
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/transportModels/lnInclude
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/meshTools/lnInclude
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/sampling/lnInclude
-IlnInclude -I.
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude
-fPIC -c src/simpleFoam.C -o Make/linux64GccDPInt32-spack/./src/simpleFoam.o
g++ -std=c++11 -m64 -Dlinux64 -DWM_ARCH_OPTION=64 -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32
-Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-cast -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-unused-parameter
-Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-attributes -O3
-Wl,-rpath,/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32-spack/lib
-DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -I./include
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/MomentumTransportModels/momentumTransportModels/lnInclude
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/MomentumTransportModels/incompressible/lnInclude
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/transportModels/lnInclude
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/meshTools/lnInclude
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/sampling/lnInclude
-IlnInclude -I.
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude
-I/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude
-fPIC -fuse-ld=bfd -Xlinker --add-needed -Xlinker --no-as-needed
Make/linux64GccDPInt32-spack/./src/simpleFoam.o
-L/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32-spack/lib
\
-lmomentumTransportModels -lincompressibleMomentumTransportModels
-lincompressibleTransportModels -lfiniteVolume -lmeshTools -lfvOptions
-lsampling -lOpenFOAM -ldl \
-Wl,-rpath,/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32-spack/lib
-lm -o ./bin/openfoam-C.out
/home/apps/spack/opt/spack/linux-centos7-cascadelake/gcc-11.2.0/openfoam-org-8-tdsvgkbzvojmqiarb4uinv5m2tceecyn/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32-spack/lib/libfluidThermoMomentumTransportModels.so:
undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char,
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
::basic_ostringstream()@GLIBCXX_3.4.26'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/openfoam-C.out] Error 1
```

Getting an error while compiling the Openfoam

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting std::\_\_cxx11::string to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring)

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

ld returned 1 exit status. The error is the consequence of previous errors. In your example, there is an earlier error—undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char—and this is the real one. The exit status error just signals that the linking step in the build process encountered some errors. Normally, exit status 0 means success, and exit status > 0 means errors.
In many cases, tools return the number of errors they encountered as the exit status. So if the ld tool finds two errors, its exit status would be 2.
Most likely you missed the < sign in std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char