# DuckDB C++ linking error: undefined reference

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, duckdb

I'm trying to use DuckDB in my project using C++ but met the linking error.

- Environment: WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04
- DuckDB binary: Directly downloaded from https://duckdb.org/docs/installation/?version=latest&environment=cplusplus&installer=binary&platform=linux
- File Structure:

  - ./src/main.cpp
  - ./third_party/duckdb/duckdb.hpp
  - ./third_party/duckdb/libduckdb.so
  - ./build
  - ./CMakeLists.txt

I stored the duckdb file path in an environment variable called DUCKDB_DIR and tried to use CMake to generate make file for a simple program which only try to call `Connection::Query()`.

Below is my CMakeFile:

```
# Set the minimum required CMake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
project(column_order)

# DuckDB
set(DUCKDB_DIR $ENV{DUCKDB_DIR})
if(NOT DUCKDB_DIR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "DUCKDB_DIR not set. Please set the DUCKDB_DIR environment variable.")
else()
    message(STATUS "DUCKDB_DIR set to ${DUCKDB_DIR}")
endif()

# Check if the libduckdb library is found
find_library(DUCKDB_LIB duckdb PATHS ${DUCKDB_DIR})
if(NOT DUCKDB_LIB)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "libduckdb not found. Please check the DUCKDB_DIR environment variable.")
else()
    message(STATUS "libduckdb found at ${DUCKDB_LIB}")
endif()

# Add the executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)

# Specify include and link directories
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${DUCKDB_DIR})

# Link the DuckDB library
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${DUCKDB_DIR}/libduckdb.so)
```

And then I generated the Makefile using cmake successfully and the message shows that `libduckdb.so` has been located. But when I try to use make command, an error occurs during linking phase, (object file `main.o` has been generated) and the message is

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/column_order.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c2): undefined reference to `duckdb::Connection::Query(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/column_order.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `duckdb::unique_ptr<duckdb::MaterializedQueryResult, std::default_delete<duckdb::MaterializedQueryResult>, true>::AssertNotNull(bool)':
...<some other similar errors>
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone give some insight of what is going on?

I also tried to directly use Makefile to generate the code, by placing `main.cpp`, `duckdb.hpp` and `libduckdb.so` in the same folder and use following Makefile:

```make
# Compiler settings - Can change to clang++ if preferred
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wall

# Since the header and so files are in the same directory as the Makefile,
# I just used -I. for includes
INCLUDES=-I.

LDFLAGS=-L.

# Libraries to link against
LDLIBS=libduckdb.so

# Name of the output program
TARGET=main

# Source files
SOURCES=main.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)


# Rule to create object files
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

# Rule to link the program
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

# Clean the build
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

# Build all targets
all: clean $(TARGET)
```

Still occur the same error.

Output for `ldd libduckdb.so`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe2edd9000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f95389cf000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f95389ac000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f95387ca000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f953867b000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9538660000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f953846c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f953b2a1000)
```

Output for `cmake -S ../` (I run `cmake` in build directory):

```
 -- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
   -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
   -- Detecting C compile features
   -- Detecting C compile features - done
   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
   -- Detecting CXX compile features
   -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
   -- DUCKDB_DIR set to /home/Caius/projects/column_order/third_party/duckdb
   -- libduckdb found at /home/Caius/projects/column_order/third_party/duckdb/libduckdb.so
   -- Configuring done
   -- Generating done
   -- Build files have been written to: /home/Caius/projects/column_order/build
```

Output for ls $DUCKDB_DIR:

```
duckdb.h  duckdb.hpp  libduckdb-linux-amd64.zip  libduckdb.so  libduckdb_static.a
```

Comment: Could you add the output ldd <your_binary> , output of your cmake command and the ls DUCKDB_DIR ?

Comment: Try this: `nm -CD libduckdb.so | grep `duckdb::Connection::Query`, do you see any output?

Comment: This sounds like a [CXX11 ABI mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring)

Comment: @Botje It is. I just checked, the library is built to pre-C++11 ABI.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yeah two related ones are : ```0000000001535590 T duckdb::Connection::Query(std::string const&)``` and ```0000000001535e70 T duckdb::Connection::Query(duckdb::unique_ptr<duckdb::SQLStatement, std::default_delete<duckdb::SQLStatement>, true>)```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Botje and n.m.couldbeanAI, this is caused by CXX11 ABI mismatch. I tried to add `add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)` in CMakeLists.txt to use older version and it solves the linking error.

Also tried to rebuild the file and it also works.

Comment: I don't recommend using -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0. Who is doing that in 2024? Just download the source instead and build it yourself. It's a singe source file. Not really rocket science.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I really had little knowledge about this so picked the straightforward way I found yesterday to see if that's the problem. Rebuilt the lib today and it works now.