cant link gtest using g++ cmake on mac
I have a simple sample gtest copied from googletest's site but linking fails with g++-13 using cmake.
Here is my CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc-13")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++-13")
project(my_project)

# GoogleTest requires at least C++14
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

enable_testing()

add_executable(
  hello_test
  hello_test.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
  hello_test
  GTest::gtest_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(hello_test)

and this is the test
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

// Demonstrate some basic assertions.
TEST(HelloTest, BasicAssertions) {
    std::cout << "hello world\n";
  // Expect two strings not to be equal.
  EXPECT_STRNE("hello", "world");
  // Expect equality.
  EXPECT_EQ(7 * 6, 42);
}

linking error
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZN7testing8internal23MakeAndRegisterTestInfoESsPKcS2_S2_NS0_12CodeLocationEPKvPFvvES7_PNS0_15TestFactoryBaseE", referenced from:
      __Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0v in test_util.cpp.o
  "__ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE4findEcm", referenced from:
      __ZN7testing8internalL21FormatDeathTestOutputERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      __ZN7testing8internal11SplitStringERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEEcPNS1_6vectorIS7_NS5_IS7_EEEE in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
...

commenting out the set c/cxx compiler lines in CMakeLists.txt and letting it use mac's clang works. it does not with g++-13.

Most likely the problem is about _cxx11 namespace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring
